# reCaptcha first timer issues

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I am trying to use reCaptcha for the first time and this is the code I wrote so far but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my html form:

```
    <form method="post" action=''>
            <cfoutput>
            <input type="hidden" name="isPost" value="1"  />


                    First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" required><br />
                    Last Name:  <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" required><br />

                    Email: <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@email.com" required><br />

                    Zip Code: <input id="zip" type="text" pattern="[0-9]{5}"  name="zipcodex" placeholder="ex. 01234" required /><br />

                    Home Phone: <input type="tel" pattern='[0-9]{10}'  name="homephone" placeholder="ex. 3335551234" required><br />

                    Cell Phone: <input type="tel" pattern='[0-9]{10}' name="cellphone" value="#cellphone#" placeholder="ex. 9990001234"><br />

                    My Interest             
                        <select class="interestOption" name="Formprocedure" id="procedure" required >
                                    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">My Interest</option>
                                    <cfloop query="procedurefinder"><option <cfif procedureid eq Formprocedure>selected="selected" </cfif>title="#procedurename#" value="#procedureid#">#left(procedurename,20)#</option>
                                    </cfloop>                                   
                                    </select><br />



                            <textarea name="comments" cols="50" rows="5" placeholder="Please enter any additional comments"></textarea><br />


                            <script type="text/javascript"
                               src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LdUMuISAAAAA********mMK5cbR1pm1AG4WV">
                            </script>
                            <noscript>
                               <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LdUMuISAAAAAMi**************mMK5cbR1pm1AG4WV"
                                   height="50" width="400" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
                               <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="0">
                               </textarea>
                               <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
                                   value="manual_challenge">
                            </noscript>
                        <br />
<button id="submit" onclick="SubmitForm();">Submit</button>



                </cfoutput>
            </form>
```

This is my JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SubmitForm(){ 
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        xmlHttp.open("POST",'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify',true); 
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
        params ="'6LdUMuISAAAAAMi4iDZ1sIuEmMK5cbR1pm1AG4WV','www.newimagespecialists.com','"+Recaptcha.get_response()+"','"+Recaptcha.get_challenge+"'"; 
        xmlHttp.send(params); 
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){ 
                if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){ 
                        if(xmlHttp.status == 200){ 
                                form.submit(); 
                        }else{
                             return false;
                        } 

                } 
        } 
} 
</script>
```

This is the response I am getting from firebug:

```
Parameters application/x-www-form-urlencoded
'6LdUMuISAA1sIuE... =typeof RecaptchaState?null:RecaptchaState.challenge}'
Source
'6LdUMAA*******IuEmMAG4WV','www.example.com','fitsesq Accord','function (){return"undefined"==typeof RecaptchaState?null:RecaptchaState.challenge}'
```

My issue is that I don't really understand where I have a mistake in the code and also why my form continues to submit? Any one can give any pointer as to where I am making a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent your form from submitting, you have to do this:

```
<form method="post" action='' onsubmit="return false">
```

In your code, you write something like:

```
Recaptcha.get_response()+"','"+Recaptcha.get_challenge
```

check that `Recaptcha.get_challenge` should be replaced with `Recaptcha.get_challenge()` and the ajax api is loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
```

And check that you create the recaptcha properly using `Recaptcha.create`

Comment: Nop, still the form goes through.

Comment: @Geo: in the code, i see you submit the form manually form.submit(); .

Comment: @Geo: onsubmit="return false" is only to prevent submitting when you click on an <input type="submit">. But if you submit your form using javascript, you need to check your script logic and correct it to not call form.submit()